# L5.2 PHP Fatal error: Declaration of Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::basic

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5

I just pushed my L5.2 app to production server. I have made a few changes, but suddenly I get the following error:

```
     PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::basic($field = 'email')
     must be compatible with
     Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\SupportsBasicAuth::basic($field = 'email', $extraConditions 
     = Array) in /home/forge/domain.com/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php on line 461
```

The app works fine locally and on the staging server.

Comment: If something succeeds in one environment and fails in the other, focus on what's different between your environments.

Answer (score 8):

just remove the bootstrap/cache/compiled.php file

`rm bootstrap/cache/compiled.php` 
then run 
`composer dump-autoload`
and

`php artisan clear-compiled`

it should work

Answer (score 2):

I solved it.

I had to do:

```
rm bootstrap/compiled.php
```

Comment: This also works for me. It had something to do with cache.

Comment: What worked for me was removing ```app/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php``` and then running ```composer dump-autoload -o```

Comment: Yes removing that file solves the error, but after few mins it gets generated again - automatically? How to solve that permanently?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you have run `composer update` on production. You should copy `composer.lock` to production server (if you haven't done it yet) and run `composer install` to install exact same version you have on your localhost

You should also run `php artisan clear-compiled` because it might be also the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as other said, removing that file solves the error.

But in my case that file gets generated again and again automatically after 1 mins. (So to keep site running I need to manually delete that file over and over :) )

So here is what I did:

Opened that bootstrap/compiled.php, removed all the content and revoke write permission for that file.

And that worked very well for me.

I know its worst/temporary solution, but unless we know the exact cause of that issue and better solution, we can use this solution.

However I don't recommend anyone to use this solution for production sites, but you can use it for just a demo site like my case.